# How to generate the LLDBFrontend in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, lldb

I made some changes for lldb which is in the llvm upstream. Then I want to replace the host lldb in the android studio. But I found in the android studio the host lldb name "LLDBFrontend" (which is under the AS code prebuilts/tools/linux-x86_64/lldb/bin/LLDBFrontend ) and is much bigger than lldb(generate from llvm). So I think I should find a way to generate LLDBFronted by using the llvm host lldb, but I haven't found any infromation about how to build LLDBFrontend until now.
I tried to execute "LLDBFrontend --version", it shows bleowed info

7.0.0 lldb version 7.0.0 (https://us3-mirror-partner-android.googlesource.com/a/platform/external/lldb revision 3fcb389d934b423a1c88d0b83590b518f43b0c40)
clang revision 4a4f14fd51a577b70a4c2464720a31fbf09a7bdf
llvm revision 4df1b8f01ec06673f219d12d3b527f6a73cbc769

Then I get the code from https://us3-mirror-partner-android.googlesource.com/a/platform/external/lldb, but still can't find how to build LLDBFrontend.

Could anyone tell me how to generate LLDBFrontend? Thanks.

Comment: I guess that's closed source, its signed by google LCC thou.

Comment: after reverse engineering it, its looks just like a protobuff client on top of the normal lldb.exe

Comment: In theory you could extract the protobuf definition and implement your own frontend by reverse engineering this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-22044