# Update LLDB in androidstudio 4.1.1

Tags: android-studio

I want to update LLDB in androidstudio 4.1.1 but I'm not able to find that in the Android studio SDKManager. Is there any other way to update LLDB?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same doubt, I guess the only way would be recompiling it and replacing `Android/Android Studio/bin/lldb/bin/liblldb.dll`

Comment: of course it didn't work, see here why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63593606/how-to-generate-the-lldbfrontend-in-android-studio